# Increment counter in mysql and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Here is my mysql query:

```
SELECT users.id, user.name, category.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(category.name) AS catName,
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_number
FROM users
JOIN usecat ON id_users=users.id
JOIN category ON id_category=category.id
CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 0) r
GROUP BY users.id
```

Result: AAA-1, BBB-3, CCC-8,...

I'd like to get this result: AAA-1, BBB-2, CCC-3,...

Can you help me change this query? Thanks.

Comment: Add more data details and expected result.

Comment: The query has *five* expressions in the SELECT list, we would expect to see a result with *five* columns.  Demonstrating the result from this statement as "**Result: AAA-1, BBB-3, CCC-8**" is abysmally inadequate.

Comment: Each user can be registered in multiple categories. I need result with counter. For example:
1(counter) - user.id, name, category1, category2 |
2 - user.id, name, category1, category2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @rownum=1;
SELECT *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_number 
FROM (SELECT users.id, user.name, category.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(category.name) AS catName
  FROM users
  JOIN usecat ON id_users=users.id
  JOIN category ON id_category=category.id
GROUP BY users.id) t;
```